# How to extract lat and long from multipolygon sf R

Tags: r, latitude-longitude, spatial, r-sf, gam

I'm trying to do a GAM with a spatial correlation, so I want to extract the latitude and longitude of the multipolygon but I'm having problems.

I have downloaded a shapefile with county data from Portugal, and I used the `sf` library. This is the information:

```
Simple feature collection with 308 features and 39 fields
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -31.26819 ymin: 30.03018 xmax: -6.189142 ymax: 42.15432
CRS:            4326

First 5 geometries:
MULTIPOLYGON (((-8.080127 39.27783, -8.080377 3...
MULTIPOLYGON (((-8.462351 40.50518, -8.462257 4...
MULTIPOLYGON (((-7.52176 40.69909, -7.529608 40...
MULTIPOLYGON (((-7.34125 38.46282, -7.341047 38...
MULTIPOLYGON (((-8.527728 40.60947, -8.528282 4...
```

I wanted to add a new column for latitude and another for longitude but I'm having issues understanding how to do this. I've tried to use `st_coordinates`, `map` and `unlist` but I always get more rows than the ones I have. Portugal has 308 counties.

Any idea, pointers how to achieve this?

Comment: st_centroid() ?

Comment: If I do `st_coordinates(st_centroid(data$geometry))` I get 308 values for lat and long, but I also get a warning `st_centroid does not give correct centroids for longitude/latitude data` so I didn't use that.

Comment: I suspect for the level of precision which your require this may not matter. See here https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/geosphere/versions/1.5-10/topics/centroid & here: https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/articles/sf6.html but ultimately that's your call.

Comment: So a `MULTIPOLYGON` can be defined by thousands of points with their own coordinates. What is your expected result? If a single point is needed you can use `st_centroid`, the warning is just telling you that your polygon is unprojected but it still compute the centroid.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, it doesn't really matter. I just thought there was another way to extract a single point but I guess `st_centroid` works.

Comment: There is a another approach, using `st_sample` with `size=1`,  but as it is random you may want to set a seed before running it to make it fully reproducible, e.g. `set.seed=NUMBER`  https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sf/versions/0.9-2/topics/st_sample

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I just started working with this library, and spatial analysis and many things are still a bit blurry.